# C++ --- cloning with multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, clone, multiple-inheritance, overriding, pure-virtual

I have a complicated inheritance structure

```
A --> B --> C --> C1, C2, C3, ...
 \     \--> D --> D1, D2, D3, ...          
  \-------> E --> E1, E2, E3, ...
```

and am trying to write a clone() function. Since B is never going to be instantiated, do I need to declare

```
virtual clone() = 0;
```

in class B? Do I need to implement it?

Also, is there a concise account of rules regarding overrides?

Comment: Your decision should be driven by the question if you need to access `clone` from `B` or any client using `B`.

Comment: My question was actually prompted by a linker error that claimed an unresolved reference to the clone in B. I was unsuccessful figuring out where and why my program might have tried to access it, other than through a mandatory interface.

Comment: It's not clear what your asking.  Can you include an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Virtual functions need to be defined or to be pure.